# MVC 3 - In a controller how do you check which items are selected in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 3 models *Albums* which has instances of *Track* and *Playlist* which also has instances of *Track*.

Currently my album view shows each track with a checkbox and a dropdown at the bottom which shows the playlists the user and a add to playlist button. So the users should be able to select tracks from the album and add them to a playlist they already have. But I'm not sure what my controller would look like to handle this. My view looks like

```
**Album View**
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Album: @Model.Title</h2>

@{

    List<Sem_App.Models.Playlist> abc = ViewBag.Playlists;

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
    from c in abc
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.PlaylistName,
        Value = c.PlaylistName,
    };
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    foreach (var track in Model.Tracks)
    {
        @Html.CheckBox(track.Title)
        @track.Title
        <br />
    }

    @Html.DropDownList("abd", selectList)

    <input type="submit" value="Add selected songs to playlist" />
}
```

My controller method looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(FormCollection fc)
{
    return View();
}
```

How can I check which tracks the user has selected and which playlist the user has selected in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your model for the album view is like `@model Album`.

Your model would be:

```
class Track
{ 
 ....
 ....
 bool IsSelected;
}
```

And then your view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()){
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tracks.Count(); i++) { 
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tracks[i].IsSelected)
       @Model.Tracks[i].Name
     }
    }
```

So you controller could be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Album album, FormCollection fc)
{
    album.Tracks;//should contain your tracks
    album.Tracks[0].IsSelected;//should return if it was selected
    fc["abd"];//should return which element was selected.
    return View();
}
```

Your view needs to be like this so the html is correctly rendered and the values are correctly bound to your controller.

You also need to use the strongly typed methods (Ending with *for*) to bind other values back into your controller. And you probably want to use `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)` to create a hidden field for the album so you know which album is posted back.

Comment: unchecked items wont be submited. So you only get checked items in action. Instead of using IsSelected property, you should set the primary key value to checkbox value. Like this. `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tracks[i].Id)`

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Tracks[i].Id) - This gives me an error that int cannot be converted to bool.

Comment: If I use the IsSelected Property, once I have selected a track I would need to unselect it after right? These tracks not only appear in albums but also under an artist's page.

Comment: @Yorgo as of MVC2 `CheckBoxFor` also renders a hidden field that stores a value, so that it returns `false` if the checkbox is unchecked. I just tested it out. See the remarks section on [msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460245.aspx)

Comment: @user972616 Not sure about your second comment, are you able to get the right data in your controller though?

Comment: @gideon The album in the controller has null values for everything apart from tracks. And each track has null values on everything apart from IsSelected

Comment: @user972616 yes because you have to bind them appropriately with the strongly typed methods. Like You would do `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)` so you get the id of the album back, and then do `@Html.xxFieldFOR()` for each field you want returned. I don't know what other fields you have but from the view you posted your using the loosely typed methods (Like `Html.CheckBox()` instead of `Html.CheckBoxFor`)